# How to insert a value in a multiple input textbox with the same class name per group using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to insert a value per group in a multiple input textbox with the same class name. I want to update the input textbox value per group. My code below is working but it is filling up all textboxes when I select an item in autocomplete. What I want is if I select an item in itemgroup 1, only textboxes in group 1 should update.

```
<div id="itemgroup1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control itemname" name="oe_type[]" placeholder="Enter item name or code" required>
  <input type="text"class="form-control it_desc" name="oe_desc[]" placeholder="Enter item description" required>                                     
  <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control it_price" name="oe_value[]" placeholder="Enter unit price" value="0">
  <input type="number" step="any" min="1" class="form-control itemqty" name="oe_qty[]" placeholder="Enter quantity" required>
</div>
<div id="itemgroup2" >
  <input type="text" class="form-control itemname" name="oe_type[]" placeholder="Enter item name or code" required>
  <input type="text"class="form-control it_desc" name="oe_desc[]" placeholder="Enter item description" required>
  <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control it_price" name="oe_value[]" placeholder="Enter unit price" value="0">
  <input type="number" step="any" min="1" class="form-control itemqty" name="oe_qty[]" placeholder="Enter quantity" required>
</div>
<script>
  $(".itemname").autocomplete({
    minLength: 4,
    autoFocus: true,
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "get_item.php",
        data: {term: request.term},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          response($.map(data.myData, function(item) {
            return {
              label: item.name,
              value: item.code,
              code: item.code,
              price: item.price,
              desc: item.desc
            }
          }));
        }
      });
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
      $(".it_desc").val(ui.item.desc);
      $(".it_price").val(ui.item.price);
      $(".itemqty").focus();
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
select: function(event, ui) {
  $(this).nextAll(".it_desc").val(ui.item.desc);
  $(this).nextAll(".it_price").val(ui.item.price);
  $(this).nextAll(".itemqty").focus();
}
```